# replace two columns with only one column representing a function of the other two

Tags: r, dataframe

I was wondering if there is a one liner command in R base to replace two columns of a matrix or a data frame with only one column which represents the result of a mathematical function applied on the two columns that are to be replaced. For instance, suppose I have this data frame:

```
> vehicle = c("bike", "car", "train", "pork")
> time = c(25,35,20,5)
> distance = c(3.2,5.4,4,8.9)
> df = data.frame(vehicle,time,distance)
> df
  vehicle time distance
1    bike   25      3.2
2     car   35      5.4
3   train   20      4.0
4    pork    5      8.9
```

and I would like to replace the last two columns with the speed of each vehicle calculated based on the time and distance columns `(df$distance/df$time)` so that the end result would be:

```
> df
  vehicle     speed
1    bike 0.1280000
2     car 0.1542857
3   train 0.2000000
4    pork 1.7800000
```

in whatever units you want. I will not bother with conversions or whatever. I am able to obtain the result, but I am curious if there is a one liner for this. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: This question is unclear to me. It seems like you already have the solution. Are you asking just how to remove two columns?

Comment: And why just base R?

Comment: @DavidArenburg I was looking for a one liner to obtain the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try either

```
data.frame(vehicle=df$vehicle, speed=df$distance/df$time)
```

Or using `transform/within` etc and remove the "time", "distance" columns

```
transform(df, speed=distance/time)[-c(2:3)]
```

Another option would be to use `transmute` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
transmute(df,vehicle=vehicle, speed=distance/time)
```